# @ResponseBody , ResponseEntity Spring return Object as JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm using Spring version 4 ( spring data), I want to return Object as JSON , I wonderd that the following code worked even without annotating the user class wtih xmlRootElement:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resources/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByLogonId(OAuth2Authentication auth) {

    String userLogonId = ((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getUserAuthentication()
            .getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    UsersServices usersServices = new UsersServicesImpl(usersOperations);
    User user = usersServices.findByLogonId(userLogonId);
    HttpStatus userStatus = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    if (user != null) {
        userStatus = HttpStatus.FOUND;
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, userStatus);
}
```

can any body explain ? is ResponseBody/ResponseEntity do the work itself ? when I need to annotate the object class to be returned as JSON.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Im using spring data

Comment: Are you using @RestController ?

Comment: Yes thats correct , restcontroller include responsebody by default  right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RestController` itself adds `@ResponseBody` annotation. You can see it in the [Github Issue](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks/issues/22)

You can also check the [official spring tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/). Here you can check the below lines and examples:

> These controller methods return simple POJOs - `Collection<Bookmark>`,
>   and `Bookmark`, etc., in all but the `add` case. When an HTTP request
>   comes in that specifies an `Accept header`, `Spring MVC` loops through the
>   configured `HttpMessageConverter` until it finds one that can convert
>   from the `POJO` domain model types into the content-type specified in
>   the `Accept header`, if so configured.

You can also follow the below lines and examples from [Official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-restcontroller)

> @RestController is a stereotype annotation that combines @ResponseBody
>   and @Controller. More than that, it gives more meaning to your
>   Controller and also may carry additional semantics in future releases
>   of the framework.

And,

> As with @RequestBody and @ResponseBody, Spring uses
>   HttpMessageConverter to convert from and to the request and response
>   streams.

Comment: I understand this but my question why xmlrootelement not needed

Comment: Yup, You have the answer on the given links. If you annotate the function with @ResponseBody or return `ResponseEntity<>` with `@RestController` the returned object will convert to JSON automatically.

Comment: @MohammadKarmi, I have edited my answer. You may review this

Answer (score 1):

`xmlRootElement` is using for representing of a object as XML element in an XML document. XML has nothing to do with JSON.
When you annotate your class by `@RestController` it combines `@Controller` for class and `@ResponseBody` for every method. And then `HttpMessageConverter` converts from and to the request and response streams.
`@ResponseEntity` is using for forming http response with custom params (headers, http code and etc.). For example:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot uses the jackson json libraries for marshalling and unmarshalling the java objects to/from json objects
no need any explicit configuration.